# A function of a constraint in a mechanics question not equaling zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, constrained-dynamics, textbook-erratum

Is this an error (I wrote what I think should be written), or is it okay that the constraint functions do not equal zero?

I thought constraint functions are of the form $g(x,\dot {x},t)=0$, so in this case we should have $g_{jk} (x, t)= (x_j-x_k)^2-l^2_{jk}(t)=0$, but here it seems they took $g _{jk}(x, t)=(x_j-x_k)^2$, which doesn't generally equal zero. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Which textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Lagrange equation for a constrained system (1)
 \begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial \mathscr L}{\partial q^i} -\frac d{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial \mathscr L}{\partial \dot q^i}\bigg) -\sum _{j=1}^{m} \lambda _j \frac{\partial \phi _j}{\partial q^i}=0  \qquad (1)
  \end{equation}
We note that since $l_{ij}\neq l_{ij}(x)$ we do not lose information regarding the constraint by eliminating this term in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood- what if $l_{ij}=l_{ji}$?

Comment: @Whyka Sorry for not being clear its like 3am here! The point I was trying to say is that on the right hand side of $(x_i-x_j)^2=l_{ij}^2$ we note that it is not a function of the $x$ coordinate and therefore when entered into (1) in the form you suggest it doesn't make too much difference. Have you tried computing the equations of motion for the book's and your Lagrangian? Do the EOM differ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your answer right- I thought you said $l_{ij}\neq l_{ji}$ and didn't understand the difference. Never mind- it is 4:30 here :-) Now I see you meant the distance between the rods is not a function of the x's but of the distances between them. You helped, thanks!

Comment: @Whyka No problem, happy to help :)